# What should I do when I see a member who leaves typos, etc. after editing?

Tags: discussion

I am not going to name him or link the post as I don't think it is fair.

I didn't notice the problems until the day before yesterday. The problem is whenever he edits a post, there remain problems, i.e. typos left, grammatical mistakes, inconsistency in editing, etc.

He even touches perfectly grammatical words or expressions.

I don't think his English is good enough to edit any post. What should I do?

Comment: Unfortunately we need more info. We should decide whether they're editing with good intentions or not by looking at the suggested edits. Note that sadly editing solely for reputation points or other imaginary rewards is relatively common in bigger sites, while it's indeed very hard to get some posts comprehensively copy edited.

Comment: I guess you are talking about me! Well, I don't blame you. But if you look at my edits and my answers, they are neatly answered and well formatted and more importantly, not **misleading** (I cannot say if you start trolling now). I will take suggestions from anyone, possibly @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ., but not from you. Whenever someone comments on my answer, or edits my post, or makes any suggestion, I happily accept it. I remember correcting two of your silly mistakes in your comment (the one that you deleted), and you went berserk.

Comment: @Usernew - I don't know if you are the mysterious unnamed member or not. For the record, though, I just went through several pages of your [revisions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/20213/usernew?tab=activity&sort=revisions), to see if I could figure out what all the hullabaloo was about. Overall, I found your edits to be a body of helpful improvements. Thank you for your hard work and thank you for making ELL a better place.

Comment: @J.R. Did you see him deleting my asterisk without even knowing what that is used for? He even posted a link that shows what the asterisk is used for and deleted it again. . Did you find the train of my editing after he left so many typos and grammatical mistakes? Why aren't you asking him to read SoneyB's answer? Do you think he is following his suggestion? Most of his editions don't.

Comment: @Rathony - Yes, I saw the flap about the asterisk that should have been left alone. My point still stands. The vast majority of Usernew's edits are helpful and useful.

Comment: Usernew isn't alone in being unfamiliar with the asterisk convention.  I think some of us forget sometimes that it's *not* obvious what it means when you mark an utterance with a special symbol like that.  That's why some of us started putting footnotes in our posts explaining what any symbols like that meant – something I've unfortunately forgotten to do lately!

Comment: @snailboat I am familiar with the use of asterisks in [Linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Linguistics), but like you said, many are not aware of it, and they might think it to be a condition, a footnote, I mean any of the use given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Typography) :) Peace Out.

Answer (score 5):

It is very difficult to tell whether this all happens *intentionally*. But in the interest of this site and being well-wishers of any learner, we should be fair on our side. Said that, even after edits, if you observe that there are mistakes, go correct them.

If you don't have enough reputation, you may simply leave a 'comment' as a suggestion. Who knows, such comments may help learn the OP as well as those who are new here.

There was/is one user who **never** bothered learning from our comments and kept on asking *unformatted* questions that took a little effort to correct. I think (I was not a moderator *then*) that the user was contacted by a moderator. These days, the questions that user posts are *much* better. Maybe, the user has learned.

Keep editing or drawing others' attention and let's see. If the user still does not improve it, do let me know. I may shoot a mail suggesting the change.

It's good to see that new users like you are helping us to keep this site up and running cleanly! :)

[Not revealing the name is good practice. But then using 'he' you revealed something ^-^]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I always use gender-neutral ***he*** for someone. :) Anyway, I will see what happens. I already gave him several  comments and told him what was wrong with his edition repeatedly. I will let you know later if I have to.

Comment: You can suggest an edit if you don't have enough reputation, which tends to work better than comments because it goes in the review queue. The only problem is that you must change at least 6 (I think) characters. @Rathony